# Is there a PHP file upload progress bar that uses the APC module and works in IE?

Tags: php, file-upload, upload, progress-bar, apc

I just installed PHP 5.2 and APC to try and use a file upload progress bar similar to this: http://www.johnboy.com/php-upload-progress-bar/

Works in FF but not in IE. In IE only the numeric value increases and the colored progress bar stays still.

I've also tried 2 other PHP/APC progress bar type things and they are also not supported by IE. Is this possible on IE?

Should I just use a flash file uploader?

Comment: I have just tried uploading a file to the link you posted using IE9, and the progress bar works.

Comment: many of my clients still use IE 8 or even IE 7.

Answer (score 0):

Well I can't say I can think of one off the top of my head. However I do know a fairly decent file uploader that works well. With php as it does a handful of other languages.

http://www.plupload.com/

It does have an IE bug in the source which is something to do with the Add file button. Which should be remedyed by finding the piece of the source code that is a filter:[